# Undefined method for form edit text value ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameter-passing

I am trying to send some data from view to controller. I am using form. I have one manufacturer controller and one user controller. What I want to do whenever I am creating new manufacturer I am also creating new user with certain values.So my form contains few values for manufacturer and few for user. I tried these things in following ways:

```
// inside ManufacturersController
def new
  @manufacturer = Manufacturer.new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @manufacturer = Manufacturer.new(manufacturer_params)
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  @manufacturer.save
  redirect_to @manufacturer
end 

 private
   def manufacturer_params
params.permit(:name, :license_no, :contact_no, :address, :country, :city, :pincode,:email_id)
 end
   def user_params
params.permit(:email, :password, :confirm_password)
  end


  // inside form view 

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email Id</label>

  <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control" name="email_id" value="<%= @manufacturer.email_id %>">
  </div>
```

```
     <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input class="form-control" name="password" value="<%= @user.password %>">  
  </div>
```

Above code is not completed code. I getting error at my form field password. It shows error `undefined method password for #<User:0x7a42580>`

Am I doing anything wrong? Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have password in your users table?

Comment: No I don't have password field but I have to create hash and salt value for password.

Comment: If you want to save the value in DB, you have to create fields.

Comment: @nilkash - I'm sure that saving password in DB is not a good idea. See [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/) post for password encryption techniques, might be helpful. And the error you are facing is obvious when you do not have column defined in table and event no setter and getter methods for it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In Rails you pass the params for a resource in a hash:

```
user: { name: 'Max' }
```

That how the built in form helpers work and it's a good practice.

When creating forms you can use the form helpers to get the correct html `name` attribute for your inputs.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do %>
  <%= f.text_field :email # user[name] %>
  <%= f.password_field :password #  user[password] %>
<% end %>
```

Rails will bind the value of `@user.email` to the email field.

When you want to create multiple records at once you can use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
  validates_associatiated :users
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

this lets you do `Manufacturer.new(name: 'Acme Corp', users_attibutes: [{ name: 'Max' }])` to create both a Manufacturer and a nested User at once.

This is how you would setup your controller

```
class ManufacturersController

  # ...

  def new 
    @manufacturer = Manufacturer.new
    @manufacturer.users.build
  end

  def create
    @manufacturer = Manufacturer.create(manufacturer_params)
    # ...
  end

  private
  def manufacturer_params
    params.require(:manufacturer)
      .permit(
        :name, :license_no, :contact_no, :address, :country, 
        :city, :pincode, :email_id, 
        users_attributes: [:email, :password, :confirm_password]
      )
  end
end
```

And your form:

```
<%= form_for(@manufacturer) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name # manufacturer[name] %>
  <%= f.text_field :license_no %>

  ...

  <%= f.fields_for(:users) do |user_fields| %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :email # manufacturer[users_attibutes][1][email] %>
    ...
  <% end &>
<% end %>
```

As @Venkat ch already has pointed out storing plaintext passwords in the database is really insecure. Use [`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) instead.

Comment: `@manufacturer.user.build` should be `@manufacturer.users.build` :)